# Flex combobox custom icon

Tags: apache-flex, combobox, icons

Trying to set the up and down state icons of a Flex Combobox to images.  I see the property for changing the color of the icon, but no property to skin it.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "properties" are actually styles on [`ComboBase`](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flex/3/langref/mx/controls/ComboBase.html#style:upSkin): `upSkin`, `downSkin`, `overSkin`, `disabledSkin`.

The default is [`ComboBoxArrowSkin`](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flex/3/langref/mx/skins/halo/ComboBoxArrowSkin.html)--take a look at the source code to get more details about overriding or customizing it.